# Simulating idle regulator for vehicles

Tags: vehicle, physx

I use PhysX vehicles for my vehicle simulation, however there is no idle regulator option available to use. I want to implement that to have correct overall engine behavior such as stalling and in the first place more plausible engine sound.

I have an idle RPM range I want to have as result of solution, let's say 900-1000.
By changing throttle value I get change in calculated RPM value.

How would I go about creating dynamic system that changes throttle accordingly to get stable RPM value?

The only option I saw was a PID controller, but as far as I know, it changes a variable to get desired result on that same variable, whereas I need to change one variable to get desired value on a different variable.